# Connecting to MS Access in Tomcat Using Context

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, jdbc

I am trying to access the MS-Access dsn created on a machine where the tomcat server is deployed.

The normal code :

Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(sun.jdbc....) did not work.

So I got the solution somewhere that it can be done using context. my current code is as below:

```
<%@  page import="java.sql.*" %>
<%@  page import="javax.naming.*" %>
<%@  page import="javax.sql.*" %>
<%
String un=request.getParameter("un");
String ps=request.getParameter("ps");
out.println("Redirected from index page<br>");
%>
<%
Connection con=null;
Statement st=null;
ResultSet rs=null;

try{

    Context initCtx=new InitialContext();
    Context envCtx = (Context)initCtx.lookup("java:comp/env");

 DataSource ds=(DataSource)envCtx.lookup("jdbc/product");
con=ds.getConnection();
st=con.createStatement();
rs=st.executeQuery("select * from login where User_name='"+un+"' and password='"+ps+"' ");
if(rs.next())
{
    session.setAttribute("user",un);
    out.println("<html> <body onload='f.submit()'> <form action='dis.jsp' name='f' </form></body></html>  ");
}
else
{
    out.println("<h1> Kindly check your username and password </h1>");
}
}

catch(Exception ex)
{
out.println(ex.getMessage());
}

%>
```

but when clicked on submit, it shows the following error:

```
Redirected from index page
Name [jdbc/product] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [jdbc].
```

Help me out.. I am new to this..

Regards.

Comment: did you specified jdbc datasource in context.xml ?

Comment: ummm.. Sorry.. I copied the code from web.. there is nothing like context.xml.. please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try putting *context.xml* under *META-INF* folder then put the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>    
<Context path="jdbc/product" docBase="ABSOLUTE_PATH_OF_PROJECT_HERE"
            debug="5" reloadable="true">
       <Resource name="jdbc/TestDB" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
                   maxActive="100" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000"
                   username="" password="" driverClassName="sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver"
                   url="jdbc:odbc:dbname"/>
</Context>
```